# jQuery datepicker return days shown/displayed

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Is there any way to get a date of the last day shown from jQuery datepicker when few months are displayed. Lets say datepicker at the moment is showing and allows to pick from 2 months (numberOfMonths: 2).  How can I get the last day that is shown on datepicker.  (if it's showing Jan&Feb, how do I get Feb 28th?)
onSelect doesn't really work because if I navigate to other months I loose the reference day. I just need to return the value of what date/month datepicker is showing to the user.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question.

Fortunately the instance object in datepicker is full of helpful data. It includes a `drawMonth` and `drawYear` so getting first date shown is fairly easy.

By setting the Date to two months ahead, with day being `zero` that will return the last day of second month.

```
$("input").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    beforeShow: function (el, ui) {
        getLastDaySHown(ui);
    },
    onChangeMonthYear: function (yr, mo, ui) {
        getLastDaySHown(ui);
    }
});

function getLastDaySHown(ui) {
    /* had to wrap in short timeout as seems data not complete when beforeSHow fires*/
    setTimeout(function () {
        var yrFirst = ui.drawYear,
            moFirst = ui.drawMonth,
            moLast = moFirst + 1 < 12 ? moFirst + 1 : 0,
            yrLast = moLast == 0 ? yrFirst + 1 : yrFirst,
            DateLast = new Date(yrLast, moLast + 1, 0);
        $('#last').text(DateLast.toString())

    }, 10);

}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5XbZM/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you're ok relying on the HTML markup, this should work:

```
$(".datePicker").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onChangeMonthYear: (function() {
        // The "logical" way would be to look for the last and not the first, 
        // but the event is fired before rendering.
        alert($(".ui-datepicker-group-first .ui-datepicker-calendar tr:last td[data-handler=selectDay]:last a").text());
    })
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y6gVM/